# How do I change the Firefox 23.0 icon back to the old one?

Tags: icon, firefox

In firefox 23.0 they use a new icon that doesn't look so much 'flat' as 'blurred' or 'smudged'. How do I go back to the old one from Firefox 22.0?

Answer (score 3):

1. Download the Firefox 22.0 release binary from one of these locations:

   - http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/22.0/mac/en-GB/
   - ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/22.0/mac/en-GB/
2. Double-click to mount the `Firefox 22.0.dmg` file.
3. Copy the icons using Terminal:

   - `cd /Volumes/Firefox/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/`
   - `cp document.icns firefox.icns /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/`
4. Reboot.

Note: If you want to do the copy from Finder, you'll need to right-click on the `Firefox.app` icon in the mounted dmg file and select "show package contents" then using a separate Finder window do the same thing for `/Applications/Firefox.app`, then change into `Contents/Resources` in both windows and copy the files across.

Answer (score 2):

- On each of the Firefox 22 and Firefox 23 apps, right click and select "Get Info".
- In each information windows that pops up, unlock the lock at the lower right (click, and enter admin credentials when prompted).
- In the Firefox 22 information window, click on the small Firefox icon at the upper left and and type <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
- In the Firefox 23 information window, click the small icon at the upper left and and type <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.
- Close the information windows; you're done.